# Samsung galaxy trend FM radio sound not going to earphones

Tags: audio, samsung, stock-android, fm-radio

my mom has Samsung galaxy trend android phone and she is having problems 
with earphones.

She wants to listen to FM radio but the sound is not going to the earphones but plays through speakers.

Are there any settings I should check?

I tested her phone with 2 earphones, the problem is the same with both of them. 
I also tried to listen to FM radio with my android (Motorola moto g) with both earphones and there are no problems there...

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is it **only** the FM radio or is the audio from other apps going to the speaker also?

Comment: For some apps it was working with the headphones but for others with speakers. For example the button pressing sounds also were going to the speakers.